# How to use Typesafe Akka with Node.js

Tags: java, node.js, scala, akka, actor

I have case that needs manipulate large stream of JSON and injecting it to Apache HBase. Our system works on Node.js with Mongo then, since we needs to enhance performance so HBase is choosen to handling the big data things.

To enchance my system scalability, I prefer using Actor Model by Akka for messaging instead any other messaging queue system. It's because Actor Model that Akka provide gives me any advantages about fail safe, Actor management, and other features that's very helpful to make my job done. But it still in JVM layer that directly injecting and consuming data from HBase.

I want my Node.js apps also works under Akka system maybe using `node-java`. Is it good practice? If it's not, is there any solution that Node.js can communicate with Akka?

ps. my question here is about how to works with Akka and Node.js, not arguing about "why choose to use Node.js when JVM has really fast JSON manipulating library?", it's because our system are already benchmarked and Node.js was the choosen one to handling JSON manipulation. Also it's already on production stage, so migration totally from Node.js to full Scala is not our priority today.

Comment: Why not implement the actor system in your HBase piece and have node talk to the actor system via http or whatever protocol?

Comment: Currently we are using RabbitMQ, but I want to achieve Actor Model by Akka with Node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, Akka implements message passing as it's concurrency model and it supports Message Queue patterns (e.g. broadcast, pub-sub). However, you'd be better off looking at MQ solutions if that is really what you need.

I think going down the path you proposed (running NodeJs with Java interop) will yield little benefit whilst adding significant complexity for the long term.

Better to look for an answer from an architectural point-of-view.

If I had to decide, I would create a Scala / Java Akka microservice that sits between your NodeJs front-end and HBase. You can get a quick Proof of Concept running (which you can back out on relatively easy).

PS. If you are committing yourself to HBase, I would highly recommend you to also look into [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/), which makes taming Big Data easier.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Actually we currently using RabbitMQ to do messaging. But after some research and implemented Akka in some of our (you can call it) `microservice` things (already in production), we like how `Actor` works, it give us very handy concept that very match to our needs.

Also we already researched about Spark and Storm, but decided to not use that. Because Spark is restricted by RDD and Storm has `fix` topology that both we can't tolerate, beside Actor Model concept, for me, is very great to implement `message driven` apps.

Comment: No probs. At the end of the day, it's all trade-off. If you are simply looking into leveraging the Actor programming model in NodeJs, have you had a look at `drama` or `nactor`? If refactoring to Java / Scala is on the cards (even in 18 / 24 months time), then it might be worth it to break down your NodeJs apps into `microservices` and slowly convert it.

Comment: Yes, I have look at drama, nactor, also senecajs, but none of them are meets our needs. Currently we had a plan about using [node-java](https://github.com/joeferner/node-java) so we can wrap our computation result and send them to Akka. But we don't have benchmark yet, also don't pretty sure about performance impact. What do you though aboout using node-java? Anyway thank you for the answer.

Comment: I never use `node-java`, but from both reading README and skimming the mailing list (in the last 10 mins), the main use case for it seems to be for ad-hoc library interop. There was a question in the mailing list that indicates that `node-java` will run the Java process from within the same NodeJs thread. As Akka have its own ways of managing threads, there could be a potential conflict (negating any benefits) of running Akka under `node-java` and/or you will come across interesting side effects.

Comment: Thank you very much about your given information. I will close this topic if no one give an answer later.

Comment: No probs. Hope I've helped.